# When login with social login mini cart count is not updating in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, customer-account, mini-cart

When login with social login like Facebook, Gmail, the mini cart items count is showing `0` and when I click on cart page then it will reload the count.

In Default Magento Login is working fine. Please refer my below screenshot for reference.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please share store URL?

Comment: It is in office server not shareable to outside

Comment: that was not working  please check this https://www.screencast.com/t/MDTPPfBqk

Comment: try this https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/magento-2-add-customer-attribute-programmatically.html

Comment: @PurushotamSharma it is not working

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your custom logic on header. By default, the mini cart on header will get data from localstorage.

I have some suggestions:

1) Reload the cart section.

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Customer:etc/sections.xsd">
    <action name="sociallogin/popup/customer">
        <section name="checkout-data"/>
        <section name="cart"/>
    </action>
</config>
```

2) The mini cart on header gets data from `localstorage`. We should follow the `localstorage` logic.

vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart/minicart.phtml

3) Browser cache

```
Status Code: 200 OK (from disk cache)
...
Pragma: cache
```

200 (from memory cache) - file found in browser, so browser is not going request from server

[image]

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665082/what-is-the-difference-between-http-status-code-200-cache-vs-status-code-304

Magento 2 comes from with Varnish cache. Using Varnish on your server can resolve the disk cache issue.

https://book.varnish-software.com/3.0/HTTP.html#pragma